# Is there any way to make a "for" loop in python double my index value after each iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop

In C++, I can easily write a for loop like below that achieves this purpose

```
for(int i = 1; i < 100; i *= 2){}
```

Is there any way to make a `for` loop in Python do the same thing?
Or is the `while` loop the only way I can do this.

Comment: You can use while loop. `while i < 100`  and inside loop `i*=2`

Comment: Read this answer for better details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17944346/3042057

Answer (score 4):

`for` loops don't do any incrementing; they iterate over an iterable instead.

You can create a generator function that produces your number sequence as an iterable:

```
def powers_of_two(start, stop=None):
    if stop is None:
        start, stop = 1, start  # start at 1, as 0 * 2 is still 0
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i *= 2

for i in powers_of_two(129):
    # ...
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in powers_of_two(129):
...     print(i)
...
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```

Answer (score 3):

A generator can be written that, somewhat similar to the C++ for loop, takes an expression in form of a lambda function to manipulate the loop variable.

```
def func_range(func, start, stop=None):
    start, stop = (0, start) if stop is None else (start, stop)
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start = func(start)


for i in func_range(lambda x: x*2, 1, 100):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the power operator.

```
In [1]: [2**j for j in range(7)]
Out[1]: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

Comment: This doesn't limit the progression to an upper limit; the OP C `for` loop only lists numbers below 100.

Answer (score 1):

A bit roundabout, but does the trick:

```
>>> for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda t: t < 100, (2**x for x in itertools.count())):
...   print(i)
... 
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
```

Answer (score 0):

[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) will do the tricks

```
def doubler(n):
    x = 1
    while x < n:
        yield x
        x *= 2


for i in doubler(100):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

A C++ for loop is really just a while loop in disguise.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i *= 2)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = 1;
while (i < 100)
{
    // do stuff
    i *= 2
}
```

So don't try to be clever. Just use a while loop.