# Use a custom order in range function Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I have been struggling with this quite a bit, and was wondering if there is a solution for this.

I would like to use the range(start,stop,step) function in Python, but I would like to use a different order than what the normal functionalities allow. From what I understand the range function can do 3 things:

1. 0, 1, 2, 3 etc
2. 10, 9, 8, 7 etc
3. 2, 4, 6, 8 etc

Now I am looking for the following order:
0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7 etc

In this case 10 in the len(df), so the last row of the df.

Comment: The `range` function can't do this, it uses a fixed step size.

Comment: Range is not done for custom ordered list of numbers. You can either use a list or create your own generator if you prefer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop with custom steps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944235/for-loop-with-custom-steps-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generator to do that:

```
def my_range(n):
    """Yields numbers from 0 to n, in order 0, n, 1, n-1..."""
    low = 0
    high = n
    while low <= high:
        yield low
        if high != low:
            yield high
        low += 1
        high -= 1
```

Some examples:

```
print(list(my_range(10)))
# [0, 10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]

for i in my_range(5):
    print(i)
    
0
5
1
4
2
3
```

This will provide every number in the interval exactly once, and lazily, just as `range`.

---

To answer the question in your comment:

if you want to mix the numbers in `your_list = [1,3,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,14]`, you can just use this function to generate the indices:

```
your_list = [1,3,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,14]
for index in my_range(len(your_list)-1):
    print(your_list[index], end=' ')

# 1 14 3 13 4 12 5 10 7 9
```

or you could build a new list in the mixed order:

```
new = [your_list[index] for index in my_range(len(your_list)-1)]
print(new)
# [1, 14, 3, 13, 4, 12, 5, 10, 7, 9]
```

Comment: That is a great solution, thanks!! One additional question, would it also be possible to do this when the numbers in the list are not gradually increasing? E.g. the numbers in the list are 1,3,4,5,7,9,10,12,13,14. And then the result should be the lowest followed by the highest and repeat: [1,14,3,13,4,12,5,10,7,9].

Comment: I added the answer to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

[`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) just has `start, stop, step` params. But you can achieve what you want by zipping two ranges together along with the `chain.from_iterable` function:

```
from itertools import chain

for val in chain.from_iterable(zip(range(11), range(10, -1, -1))):
    print(val)

# 0 10 1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5 5 6 4 7 3 8 2 9 1 10 0
```

Note this solution repeats values, if you want no repeated values, then a generator is the way to go.

Comment: `ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Oops typo, fixed.

Comment: This produces `0 10 1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5 5 6 4 7 3 8 2 9 1 `, with some duplicated values, which is probably not what the OP expected...

Comment: Now it's `0 5 1 4 2 3 3 2 4 1 `

Answer (score -1):

To keep things simple and clear the range function cannot do this.
Since it only allows to either increment or decrement at once.

but this can be achieved with loops and variables.

this is how to do it

```
for i in range(0,11):
    print(i,10-i,end=" ")
```

this code will do it.

Comment: but this can be achieved with loops and variables : how?

Comment: from itertools import chain

for val in chain(*zip(range(10), range(10, -1, 0))):
    print(val)

Comment: That's the same as @Moosefeather 's answer.

Comment: i have edited the answer plz check if it helps

Comment: Well.. I guess it's better