# How to make a list in range with number space?

Tags: python, list

I want to make a list in the range of **X** to **y** with a **k** number gap.

Where x = 10, y = 70, k = 15.

the required list looks like as

```
list = [10, 25, 40, 55, 70]
```

Comment: `list(range(10, 75, 15))` the 3rd parameter in range is the step

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop with custom steps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944235/for-loop-with-custom-steps-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The `range` function has 3 arguments: `range(start,end,step)`. `start` is 0 by default. `end` is the number where `range` will stop. `step` is the increment with each value. Its default value is 1.

A point to note that the `range` function stops at `end-1`. So if you want to include your final number, just add 1 to it as done in the example.

```
a = 10
b = 70
c = 15
list_numbers=list(range(a,b+1,c))
print(list_numbers)
```

Comment: @AnuragDabas, no, but I just wanted to explain the ```range`` function. But np, I'll delete it

Comment: Nice explaination +1

Comment: @AnuragDabas, where is your answer?

Comment: That was Incomplete without explaination **;)**